# Deserialize generified Enum

Tags: java, enums

I want to deserialize a generic enum. Sender and receiver use `ObjectMapper` for `MAPPER`:

```
String data = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(new ChangeState(this.state.toString(), this.state.getClass()));
bus.talkAsync(exchangeName, ROUTE_SET_STATE, data);
```

The Class `ChangeState`

```
public record ChangeState<E extends Enum<E>>(String someInfo, String state, Class<E> stateType) {}
```

The object being sent could look like this:
`{"someInfo":"Test","state":"IDLE","stateType":"com.demo.common.states.ServiceAState"}`
`{"someInfo":"Test","state":"SOME","stateType":"com.demo.common.states.ServiceBState"}`

I deserialize the message like this:

```
ChangeState<? extends Enum<?>> changeState = MAPPER.readValue(message, ChangeState.class);
```

But I'm unable to use the enum afterwards. How can I get back the enum (e.g. with `valueOf`)?

#### What I've tried

##### Cast

The following does not work, because `stateType` is an unknown class:

```
Class<? extends Enum<?>> stateType = changeState.stateType();
Enum<?> state = (stateType) changeState.state(); // Error thrown here for the cast type
```

##### Transmit the enum as enum

I tried to send the enum directly:

```
public record ChangeState<E extends Enum<E>>(String someInfo, E state) {}
```

But this leads to an error, because the enum type can't be identified, since the message looks like this: `{"someInfo":"Test","state":"IDLE"}`.

#### Additional

- Each service has it's own state enum, since each service can have different states. The main target ist to make a service, which keeps track of all the states of every other service
- It's a multi module project. Every module uses the `com.demo.common` module to share classes. The used enums are usable in all modules.
- `bus` is a RabbitMQ BusConnector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a constant name and a class, you can use the static [two-argument valueOf method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String)) to convert the name to an enum value:

```
String name = changeState.state();
Class<? extends Enum<?>> type = changeState.stateType();
Enum<?> state = Enum.valueOf(type, name);
```